# Difference in 3 Cypher queries

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have three similar queries in Cypher that produces different results.

Q1 - returns result in about 110ms on average

`MATCH (a:person {pid:'48'})-[:FRIEND*2..2]->(fof) 
WHERE NOT (a)-[:FRIEND]->(fof) 
RETURN fof.pid`

Q2 - returns result in about 70ms on average

`MATCH (a:person {pid:'48'})-[:FRIEND]->(f) 
WITH a, COLLECT(f) as friends 
MATCH (a)-[:FRIEND]->(:person)-[:FRIEND]->(fof) 
WHERE NOT (fof IN friends) 
RETURN fof.pid`

Q3 - Doesn't return a result in a comparable time

`MATCH (a:person {pid:'48'})-[:FRIEND]->(:person)-[:FRIEND]->(fof:person) 
WHERE NOT (a)-[:FRIEND]->(fof) RETURN fof.pid`

What is essentially the difference here?

EDIT:

version - Neo4j 2.2.0-M03, embedded DB

Comment: Could you please check with Neo4j 2.2.0-M04 (NB: it's a milestone - not intended for production)? 2.2 has a cost based cypher optimizer that might have different results regarding to runtime of the query.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Sorry, I should've mentioned, I'm actually using Neo4j 2.2.0-M03 version. Would it be different with M04? I'm getting these results with the database embedded in java.

Comment: The queries return different things because they're different.  Q1 & Q3 doesn't allow `a` to be linked to `fof`, but Q2 does permit that, it seems.  If you `PROFILE` these, their access patterns look pretty different, particularly Q2.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Q2 doesn't permit linking to fof either by using `WHERE NOT (fof IN friends)` clause. isn't it? From the way I understood, all three queries does the same thing...

Comment: Yes, they do return very different access patterns, and with the database I'm on, profiling Q3 left the console hanging. For Q1 and Q2, total database accesses return very close results.  I'm not sure I understand what's going on here.